# What should I use to normalize data in a web app on client side?

Tags: javascript

I want to get rid of the *nested structured*, *denormalized* data responses from my http server it gets from my database server (Postgresql) and its intentionaly *normalized* design data model by me. I want to do this in order to have better control on the data I have on the client side. I frequently need to mutate data on client side with user input and with server responses.

I use *React.js* in the front end for GUI, in web browser. There are some candidates, and one is [normalizr.js](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr), which may be only meant to be used with  Redux.js or Flux. I require not to depend on the *Redux.js* or *Flux.js*. I need to use it just with *React.js*.

What software libraries should I use to achieve this?

- must work with *React.js* directly
- must work without another intermediary (such as Redux.js or Flux)

Comment: I have asked on meta: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2603/what-to-do-with-the-closed-questions

Comment: I want to make this question on-topic again rather than delete it.

Comment: I see. Also congrats to your question on Meta, very good approach! OK, a little more help then: Please take a look at our [question guideline](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for what facts are still missing (e.g. is it Javascript, node.js, JQuery? `.js` is not clear enough – though Redux/Flux might be indicators to those familiar with them). Any other specific requirements? Need for commercial use? Any budget, or must it "come for free"? // Btw: I'm going to cleanup comments a little, so don't wonder for those disappeared.